# How to use 'client' inside a cog-file [Discord.py]

Tags: python, discord

so i just started programming Discord-Bots and wanted to use cogs to keep everything organized.
Now i want to use 'client' inside the cog:

cog file:

> ```
> import discord
> from discord.ext import commands
>
> class Manage(commands.Cog):
>
>     def __init__(self, client):
>         self.client = client
>
>     ### Events ###
>     @commands.Cog.listener()
>     async def on_ready(self):
>         print(f'We have logged in! xD')
>
>     ### Commands ###
>     @commands.command()
>     async def ping(self, ctx):
>         await ctx.send(f"Pong! Response time:{round(client.latency * 1000)}ms")
>
> def setup(client):
>     client.add_cog(Manage(client))
> ```

I have the main file connected to the cog and everything works fine until that i can use 'client' in the cog file.
Plz help <3

Comment: It's available as `self.client` in all the methods of the cog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beginning of your class should look like

```
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
```

Within the rest of your code. You can use `self.bot` within your cog to reference client